# Drupal 8 search api - how to get the url of contents

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm trying to implement a content search functionality in drupal 8 based web site.i'm using search API module for content search([https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) I've searched for search API implementation videos on YouTube. They are creating search index and printing the results by creating a  view. I've a doubt regarding url of the contents. How can I get the url of the results so that I can navigate to the page from search results page. Also how can I get the page url in case the particular result is a block? Is there any other module that provides better functionality?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the node ID (nid) to create the path. Add a *Datasource ID* field to your View, and then use Twig to render your link in the View template.

**Example**

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': fields.nid.content}) }}">
    {{ 'View node page'|t }}
</a>
```